# Offset Line Symbology in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, line

I have a line feature that I offset by altering the symbology from "simple line" to "cartographic line" and then adjusting the offset.  However, this segmented the line in many places. I tried a dissolve thinking it was due to being multipart, but it only made a minor change.

Any idea how to correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see if these lines are offsetting in different directions?  If so, then I think your lines were drawn in different directions.  That is, one was drawn from left to right and the other from right to left.

To fix this, you need to flip one of the lines.  It's up to you to determine what makes sense.  Whether you fix the one on the top, or the one on the bottom.

**Step 1:** Make your feature class editable.

[image]

**Step 2:** Select one of the lines with the edit tool on the Editor Toolbar.

[image]

**Step 3:** Click on the Edit Vertices tool on the Editor Toolbar.

[image]

**Step 4:** Right click on the line and select Flip.

[image]

**Step 5:** Stop editing and save your edits.

[image]

Note, this may have a cascading effect on other lines further down if there are others connected that were drawn the same way.  To quickly check the order of your lines, change the symbology to something with an arrow.  I like this one with the arrow at the end:

[image]

It will allow you to quickly see at glance the order that the lines were drawn.

Comment: Ultimately, after trying these different options, the flip was the quickest and easiest solution, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS 10.3 there is a new tool called Edge Match Features (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/using-the-edge-match-tool.htm) and Generate Edgematch links (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/generate-edgematch-links.htm) that will link line endpoints to one another based on a search radius and attribute information.

You could also try using Extend Line (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/extend-line.htm) and, subsequently, snapping (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm).

[image]

[image]